# Limpar input - ng-model - change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Possuo um `md-select` onde de acordo com o selecionado, crio algumas div's usando `ng-if`. Essas div's criadas possuem em 02 delas, modelos(ng-model) iguais. Assim sendo, quando realizar a troca de md-select para outro que possua o mesmo modelo, o valor setado nesse campo será mantido. Gostaria de verificar a possibilidade de limpar tal modelo sempre que houve um change de campo!?

```
<div ng-if="input.Tipo == 4">                                        
    <div class="col-md-8">                                      
        <md-input-container>
            <label ng-if="input.Descricao">{{ input.Descricao }}</label>
            <label ng-if="input.Descricao == undefined"> Data </label>
            <md-select ng-model="input.SequenciaTipoData">
                <md-option value="1">Dia Atual</md-option>
                <md-option value="2">Ontem</md-option>
                <md-option value="3">Início do Mês Atual</md-option>
                <md-option value="4">Início do Mês Anterior</md-option>
                <md-option value="5">Fim do Mês Anterior</md-option>
                <md-option value="6">Data Fixa</md-option>
                <md-option value="7">Retroagir X Dias</md-option>                                                    
            </md-select>                                            
        </md-input-container><br />           
    </div>

    <div ng-if="input.SequenciaTipoData == 1 || input.SequenciaTipoData == 2">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Horário</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="input.Valor" ng-pattern="/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}$/" required>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>                          
    </div>                                   

    <div ng-if="input.SequenciaTipoData == 6">
        <div class="col-md-2" >
            <md-datepicker ng-model="input.Valor"  md-placeholder="informe data" md-current-view="month" md-open-on-focus required></md-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="input.SequenciaTipoData == 7">
        <div class="col-md-2" >
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Quantidade Dias</label>
                <input ng-model="input.Valor" maxlength="365" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não é só usar `$scope.$watch`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nçao conheço essa propriedade. Teria alguma exemplo? Grato!

Comment: Serve para você criar uma funcionalidade no controller para assistir a mudança de uma variável...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters estou tentando aplicar na minha solução, mas sem sucesso até momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O AngularJS possui uma diretiva para detectar mudanças: [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Minha sugestão é que você crie uma função para limpar o que você deseja limpar e use o ng-change no select.

Ex.: `<md-select ng-model="input.SequenciaTipoData" ng-change="limparModel()">`

Boa sorte! :)